# Absolute/Fixed header in table with scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, clusterize

I have a table with data I don't control (it comes from the user). We use a plugin called [Clusterize](https://github.com/NeXTs/Clusterize.js) that let's us smoothly scroll tens of thousands of rows which has some specific type of markup it needs (you'll see "clusterize" classes in my JSBin).

The problem is that on computers that have scrollbars like Windows or OS X with a mouse plugged in there's no scrollbars on our fixed table header which makes it so when you horizontal scroll it doesn't scroll right at the same "pace" as the the whole table overflow because of the difference in widths or something. I have an example of the behavior in the JSBin link.

Again tho, on computers WITH scrollbars. You can turn on scrollbars all the time in OS X preferences too.

http://output.jsbin.com/wekafiq

Here's some screenshots too. the first is *not* scrolling and the 2nd is when you scroll to the right.

[image]

[image]

I'm open to any possible fixes that are CSS only, JS only, or whatever else. I've spent like 2 days trying different things and this is the closest I've gotten and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Problem with it as separate and outside the table (if I understand what you mean) is that the rows will be a different width. Like `Rank`. If I remove `Rank` the `Rank` column with numbers collapses to just fit `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. I need `Rank` in the table DOM so it knows how wide to make the column to fit the `Rank` text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar question has been already discussed in Clusterize's gitter, check out https://gitter.im/NeXTs/Clusterize.js

You could add separate table outside of the main table just for headers and keep it synced with main area columns width.

Example http://codepen.io/NeXTs/pen/ZbmWqg

```
var fitHeaders = (function() {
  var prevWidth = [];
  return function() {
    var $firstRow = $('#contentArea tr:not(.clusterize-extra-row):first');
    var columnsWidth = [];
    $firstRow.children().each(function() {
      columnsWidth.push($(this).width());
    });
    if(columnsWidth.toString() == prevWidth.toString()) return;
    $('#headerArea tr').children().each(function(i) {
      $(this).width(columnsWidth[i]);
    });
    prevWidth = columnsWidth;
  }
})();

var clusterize = new Clusterize({
  rows: data,
  scrollId: 'scrollArea',
  contentId: 'contentArea',
  callbacks: {

    // Update headers width on cluster change
    clusterChanged: function() {
      fitHeaders();
    }
  }
});

// Update headers width on window resize
$(window).resize(_.debounce(fitHeaders, 150));
```

Comment: I think you got the wrong impression of my question @Denis :) This is about scrolling. I'm not concerned with the sticky headers being sticky, but to the right. In your example  once the table content causes it to scroll (which it needs to scroll in my app) the headers are no longer synced above. I have screenshots above, but here's what your example looks like scrolled  http://take.ms/XJexK

Comment: Oh, this was the CSS I added to your example: .clusterize {
  width: 500px;
}
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

Comment: @OscarGodson yep, my fault, how about this one http://codepen.io/NeXTs/pen/yeLPGa

Comment: Your last comment definitely did it! It needed a bit of tweaking like I mentioned in chat where I included a hidden table header row in the clusterize data table so that the sizing would be correct in the faux table header above